# How to execute JavaScript with JavaScriptCore framework?

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, jasmine, javascriptcore

I have implemented following code to execute JavaScript file of [Jasmine Test](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) Framework.

```
NSMutableArray * fArr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"js" inDirectory:@"scripts/JS_TestFramework/lib/jasmine-1.1.0"];
NSMutableString *fullFrameworkScript = nil;
    NSString *script;

    for (int i = fArr.count-1; i >= 0; i--) 
    {
        NSMutableString* filePath = [fArr objectAtIndex:i];

        fullFrameworkScript = [NSMutableString string];

        NSError*    error;

        script = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

        if(script)
        {
            [fullFrameworkScript appendString:script];
        }
    }
    JSValueRef result;
if(fullFrameworkScript)
    {
        JSStringRef scriptJS = JSStringCreateWithCFString(fullFrameworkScript);

        JSValueRef exception = NULL;

        result = JSEvaluateScript(context, scriptJS, NULL, NULL, 1, &exception);

        if(exception)
        {
            [self logException:exception];
            exception = NULL;
        }

        JSStringRelease(scriptJS);
    }

JSStringRef step1 = JSStringCreateWithCFString(@"jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmine.TrivialReporter())");

JSValueRef exception = NULL;

    JSObjectRef fn          = JSObjectMakeFunction(context, step1, 0, NULL, JSStringCreateWithCFString(script), NULL, 0, NULL);
    result      = JSObjectCallAsFunction(context, fn, NULL, 0, NULL, &exception);

    if(exception)
    {
        [self logException:exception];
        exception = NULL;
    }

    JSStringRelease(step1);

    [MTPScriptExecutionContext removeAllObjects];

    JSStringRef htmlResult = JSValueToStringCopy(context, result, NULL);

    NSString *htmlData = [NSMakeCollectable(JSStringCopyCFString(kCFAllocatorDefault, htmlResult)) autorelease];

    JSStringRelease(htmlResult);

    return htmlData;
```

This is my function which returns HTML data... When i am executing the script i am getting following error at Exception:

```
Exception = Can't find variable: jasmine
```

Though my script has declared `jasmine` variable at first line. What else could be the problem with above code????  Is their any other way to execute JavaScript??

One more question : Does JavaScriptCore framework supports DOM and other functionality of HTML??

Answer (score 2):

For your second question, JavaScriptCore doesn't support DOM and other HTML related stuff. It's a minimal engine which implements ECMA 262(?) specification. DOM support are implemented in WebCore which is a part of WebKit.

Go with PhantomJS if you want to do headless JavaScript/DOM tests